# WinRt PasswordBox show button "Show password"

Tags: winrt-xaml, passwordbox

I'm developing an app for windows store and using PasswordBox in it. When I enter symbols in empty box - button "Show password" is showing. But when I edit value or copy symbols into passwordbox - there is no button. 
Xaml:

```
 <ScrollViewer Margin="10,15,20,15">
 <Grid Margin="35,35,150,35" Visibility="Collapsed">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    ...
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
     <PasswordBox x:Name="pxPass" IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled ="True" Grid.Row="6"/>
    ...
 </Grid>
```

Code:

```
    private void btnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pxPass.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        pxPass.Password = 'string';
    }`
```

What can I do in this in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I edit value or copy symbols into passwordbox - there is no
>   button.

Of course that is possible, the visibility of the `password reveal button` is determined by many things, not only the value of the `IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled` property.

The value of this property is not the only factor that determines whether a password reveal button is visible to the user in UI. *Other factors include* whether **the control is displayed above a minimum width**, whether the **PasswordBox has focus**, and whether the **text entry field contains at least one character**.

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.passwordbox.ispasswordrevealbuttonenabled

Comment: Thank you! All factors observed, but when I edit text into passwordbox - button is still not visible.

Comment: @DariaKorosteleva this is weird, I'm testing it right now, and it works pretty neat for me, are you sure you are not setting or doing something else we should be aware of ? can you share your full code please ??

Comment: I share full code, where I use passwordbox, in main question. Thank you!

Comment: This is weird, try to do the same thing again in a new project, and see what goes on.

Comment: Thank you so mutch for your help! I created new app with passwordbox. While the focus in the box - everything is working great. But when I move focus on another element, password reveal button is no longer displayed. Even after the focus is returned. I think, passwordbox need just for lockscreen, example. In my case I need to use textbox and checkbox on the side.

Comment: @DariaKorosteleva : welcome, well :

`when I move focus on another element, password reveal button is no longer displayed.`

of course, as it is described above, the PasswordBox must have focus to show the reveal button.

`Even after the focus is returned.` 

You should be sure that the focus is set